# How do I type a 'soft return' in stackoverflow Q&A?

Tags: support, markdown

How do I type a 'soft return' in stackoverflow Q&A?
Of course I can type 'shift enter' but it produces a hard return and a blank line.
I want a new line without a blank line.

Comment: What purpose do you have for this? I don't see a use case for this feature.

Comment: You must be kidding me? 

Anybody:   how to get a newline in a comment - T.O.'s comment is my use case.

Comment: No newlines in  
comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specifically answer your question:

To have a new
line
like
this.  Simply follow the end of the first line with 2 spaces and then a new line.

[Here is the source of above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/0ff739d8-308d-40a8-8e07-0533aff8ef55/view-source)

Comment: Funny, I always just used a br tag.

Comment: @Brian, you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

See

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

which is linked from

- the small [?] to the upper right of every edit area
- the "full reference" link in the sidebar of any ask or edit page
- the /faq

(search for `<br` or `linebreak` if you can't find it in the file, but it is near the top)

Comment: Very useful link

Comment: @Gerard: The link is always available for you, when you type an answer/question on SO. Click the question mark in the upper right of the text box.